# Find corrupted files/folder?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine

My iMac, running macOS 10.12.6, was* acting slow and at least one application isn't working properly. I believe the issue is the hard drive, possibly corrupted files. I rebooted into recovery mode and checked the boot-up volume, and Disk Utility doesn't identify anything wrong with it.

I decided to make sure my backup was up-to-date, and dug out my drive from moving house a month ago. It was going along at a good clip and then slowed way down. Since then I've tried copying files with the Finder, `rsync` and  Beyond Compare but it is taking forever.

Is there a way I can identify the files that are problematic? Can I scan a copying app in Activity Monitor, see data in system.log, or invoke `lsof` with specific parameters to show me? My hope is that one folder is bad, and I can delete it, finish the backup, and wipe and re-install.

Note that my computer has a fusion drive.

---

'* On a happy note, I followed some instructions saying to start up in safe mode to fix issues with time machine stalling, and, while it didn't fix my backing up issue, the computer is much more responsive. One of my key applications still doesn't work, though.

---

**Additional Info**

I believe files are corrupted for two reasons.

1. Time Machine was backing up files quickly for the first, say, 20 GB of 60 GB in a couple of hours or less, and then it slowed to a crawl -- on the order of hundreds of megabytes in a day. I'm backing up with rsync right now on the order of 500 kB/s.

   - I just cancelled the ongoing backup and did a speed test by creating an empty 100 MB file on my internal and backup drives (using `dd`). [I only did it once]:

     - Internal: 113 MiB/s
     - External: 214 MiB/s
     - Copy from Internal to External: 217 MB/s
2. I develop Android games for Unity. I synced up to one of our projects to build it and got Gradle errors. After a lot of diagnostics (the specific details of which my memory has suppressed :-) ), I determined that the build failed because one of the Java libraries on my computer was corrupt. I deleted my JDK and installed a newer one (1.8u161, IIRC), and, well, Unity complains that I don't have a JDK installed even when I give it the path.

Comment: Could you post details of the key application that isn't working, including any errors? If you could post why you believe files are corrupted even though Disk Utility isn't reporting anything I believe that would be helpful in trying to understand the problem also.

Comment: I have added the requested details, @Scottmeup.